# iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance changes Request.MapPath

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, iis-7, itext

I've been stuck on this problem all night. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything related to my exact problem. On our IIS server we have a page that creates a pdf. We put an image in the header of the created PDF. This had been working properly until last night when we updated some unrelated code on different pages. Now when we try to create the PDF we get an error that the image file doesn't exist. Here's the weird part, iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance is changing the path we send to it?

Here's the line of code
Dim oImage As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Request.MapPath("~/images/" & sLogo))

If we output the results of Request.MapPath("~/images/" & sLogo) we receive
E:\Inetpub\sitename\images\logo.jpg

When we place it in in the iTextShart.text.Image.GetInstance() function our path output changes to
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\images\defaultlogo.jpg

You can see the logo itself changes too, it should be noted that we do use DefaultLogo.jpg in the case that a client doesn't use their own logo but all the ones i'm testing with do. The path E:\Inetpub\sitename\images does exist and logo.jpg does exist.

Here's the weirdest part, if i change the path from images to image
IE: iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Request.MapPath("~/image/" & sLogo))

the output will be
E:\Inetpub\sitename\image\logo.jpg

So i have no idea why images doesn't resolve.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if this answer has been posted before and i just can't find it i'm very sorry, and if you could point me to that i would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, and it's sheer stupidity on my part. The page we call to create the pdf had bad security on it. Basically we were looking for a session variable that didn't exist and redirected that page to a session time out notice. Removed that session check and it's working now!